# How can I jump from a Handler started from a service to the service's thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I use a Handler in my Service class to do some background work, but when it's done, I must execute some code on the Service's thread. Here's my code:

**I create a handler in the Service's onCreate method.**

```
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(getPackageName());
    handlerThread.start();
    Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
    mHandler = new Handler(looper);
```

**How I use the Handler. This method is getting called dozens of times during a session.**

```
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
              // It takes a few seconds to execute this method, 
              // so it must be running on a separate thread.
              Object o = superMethod();

              // However, this MUST be called from the Service's thread.
              useObject(o);
        }
    };)
```

So how can I get back to the Service's thread?

Comment: Service by default runs on main thread i.e. UI Thread in Android, so you can use runOnUiThread() method.

Comment: It doesn't inherit any kind of runOnUiThread() method. As far as I know, only Activities have this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service itself runs on main thread here you want switch from Handler Thread(Background thread) to service(main Thread).

```
Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        handler .post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do your main thread task here
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you please up the answer.